# Unsatisfied Link Error javax.media

Tags: java

When I attempt to run my program I am getting this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: 
javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.getAWT()J
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.getAWT(Native Method)
at javax.media.j3d.MasterControl.<init>(MasterControl.java:517)
at javax.media.j3d.VirtualUniverse.<clinit>(VirtualUniverse.java:253)
at javax.media.j3d.TransformGroupRetained.setTransform(TransformGroupRetained.java:126)
at javax.media.j3d.TransformGroup.setTransform(TransformGroup.java:121)
at simbad.sim.BaseObject.create3D(Unknown Source)
at simbad.sim.StaticObject.create3D(Unknown Source)
at simbad.sim.Arch.create3D(Unknown Source)
at simbad.sim.Arch.<init>(Unknown Source)
at MyEnv.<init>(MyEnv.java:5)
at MyProg.main(MyProg.java:4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please provide more insight into this. As mentioned in the [Java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError.html), an `UnsatisfiedLinkError` is thrown if the Java Virtual Machine cannot find an appropriate native-language definition of a method declared native.

Comment: Which typically is a DLL or .so file not properly available.